# Bitmap drawing with multiple threads | Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas, bitmap

What I want to do?: 
- Draw a huge amount of random points (100k - 10M) onto a Bitmap.

Since this is time consuming I want to split it into 4 threads.
Each thread should calculate one quarter of the Image.

1) Is it possible for all 4 threads to draw on the same Bitmap and gain some performance?

I've had implemented it alread with each Thread getting the same Bitmap reference but using its own Canvas (for the drawing operation). But this did not decrease the time however. Hence i thought the different canvas from the threads are always waiting for an operation to be finished on the same Bitmap (=> Canvas operation is thread-safe ?!).

Now I thought to use 4 ImageViews with 4 Bitmaps where each thread gets its own Bitmap but i have some Layout problems. I have tried GridLayout (2x2) but cannot get it working, so each ImageView gets a quarter of the Grid.
I have assigned them to each spot (0x0) - (0x1) - (1x0) - (1x1) and set them to match_parent in heigth and width but no succes.

2) Which Layout would be the best choice to implement 4 childviews (ImageView) which are put into each quater of the Layout

With best regards
Tak3r07